# VS2017 Pro v 15.9.53 c# .net 4.7.2 After Adding communitytoolkit.mvvm 8.1.0 to new wpf project, get warnings IDE0006 and MSBuild error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, mvvm, nuget

I am trying to learn how to use the Microsoft CommunityToolkit.mvvm for a work project. I am building the project via VS2017 Right click build, rebuild menu.  I have limited knowledge of MSBuild.

I created a simple Wpf App, nothing but a mainwindow.  Compiled with no errors.

Next, I added the CommunityToolKit.mvvm Stable version 8.1.0.  Warnings were immediately generated.

1. IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.
2. Invalid static method invocation syntax: "[MSBuild]::VersionLessThan($(MVVMToolkitCurrentCompilerVersion), 4.0)". Method '[MSBuild]::VersionLessThan' not found. Static method invocation should be of the form: $([FullTypeName]::Method()), e.g. $([System.IO.Path]::Combine(`a`, `b`)).

If I close and reopen the project, None of the project references can be found.

Searched for Invalid static method of invocation syntax on internet as well as communitytoolkit.mvvm issues.
No searches were helpful given my limited knowledge of the ms build environment.
Reviewd: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/update-to-1580-projects-wont-load/311136
my gacutil results show MSBuild items for 12, 4, 3.5, 2, but nothing for 15.x.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: .NET 4.7.2 is no longer supported. Any reason you can't upgrade to 4.8?

Comment: CommunityToolKit.mvvm doesn’t support any version of .NET Framework. https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Mvvm/#supportedframeworks-body-tab

Comment: MSBuild added `VersionLessThan` in a newer version of VS/MSbuild than 2017. I don't remember if it's in VS2019, you might need to upgrade to VS2022 for it to work.

Comment: if possible, could you please share the related code?

Comment: @padeso Thank You for your response.  what I had read previously indicated the Framework was supported.  Looking at your link, it clearly shows it is not.

Comment: @zivkan Thank You for your response.   It is not an option to upgrade to vs2022 and .net 6 or later for this project.  We will be upgrading after this project.

Comment: @PMF Thank you for your response.  The comment added by padeso pointed out the project depencies do not support the .net Framework so upgrading to 4.8 will not help.

Comment: @Bowman Zhu-MSFT As padeso pointed out,  this package does not support .net Framework, so posting code will not be helpful at this point I think.

Comment: @padeso is the correct answer.  I cannot find a way to mark this as the correct answer. There is no  checkmark icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CommunityToolKit.mvvm doesn’t support any version of .NET Framework: https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Mvvm/#supportedframeworks-body-tab