Build errors when using CommunityToolkit.MVVM with Visual Studio extensions
I'm getting build errors despite the SourceGenerator apparently working correctly. Example code:
namespace VisGit.ViewModels
{
    public partial class MainViewModel: ObservableObject
    {     
        [ObservableProperty]
        string _exceptionMessageText = "Exception Text";

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            ExceptionMessageText = "Test Change";
        }
    }
}

Intellisense shows the public property ExceptionMessageText as being generated successfully:

Also, source generator appears to work:

However, I get the build error The name 'ExceptionMessageText' does not exist in the current context:

UPDATE:
I've narrowed it down. If I just make a viewmodel class by itself, it works as expected. However, trying to bind it to the view is what breaks it:
<UserControl x:Class="VisGit.Views.MainView"
                xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:VisGit.ViewModels">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewmodels:MainViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>

If I remove the above, I don't get the error.
You can find illustrative code here (ignore VisGit.Core - that's for another issue):
Github code

If you look at the intro page for the toolkit there's a list of requirements. Platform and Runtime Independent - .NET Standard 2.0, .NET Standard 2.1 and .NET 6

So just to double check I'm not missing anything - it should run with Framework 4.8, right?

If so - this seems in direct contradiction to this SO post (although I'm sure about their interpretation of the nuget page - light blue means "compatible with").. Confusion reigns.

Ooops. Link for above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75837783/vs2017-pro-v-15-9-53-c-sharp-net-4-7-2-after-adding-communitytoolkit-mvvm-8-1-0/75864727?noredirect=1#comment138613344_75864727

Hi @stigzler, i cloned your code and built in my VS2022 and no errors. Please see the output? Not sure if I missed something.

You may have been compiling a different version which doesn't try to assign the Public Property a value?  I've just started from scratch due to crap with VS + Extension Dev (new install) and whilst it worked initially, I soon had the same error return. It's basically dodgy code - Sergio has suggested I put my view models in a separate lib, which isn't really a very good solution, but all I have atm and trying that presently...

Hi ,Could you please share the repro steps of build the project to help me  compile the same version with you?

Have narrowed it down a bit more and linked to some specific code to illustrate. See OP

Be able to reproduce the same issue at my side. Will let you know if there is any update.

Just read this hack.md in your repo and it seems that  you've found a workaround.

I cannot comment since I do not have enough reputation, but one thing to keep in mind is that fields are typically not used for data binding (I suppose that is your goal since you are using ObservableObject). Reference
Regarding your question in the comments, if the toolkit supports .NET Standard 2.0, it should run .NET Framework 4.8 just fine. However, that page says it is not always supported with tooling:

The versions listed for .NET Framework apply to .NET Core 2.0 SDK and later versions of the tooling. Older versions used a different mapping for .NET Standard 1.5 and higher. You can download tooling for .NET Core tools for Visual Studio 2015 if you cannot upgrade to Visual Studio 2017 or a later version.

I do not know what Visual Studio version or MsBuild versions you are using but that might be your problem?

Hey - thanks for the contribution. I'm on VS2022 - not sure of my MSBuild version - just the standard for VS2022?

@stigzler I believe VS2022 will use the MsBuild that came installed with it. One another note, I just looked at your code at GitHub and noticed that the ExceptionMessageText is missing from the MainViewModel. Not sure if I missed something but it seems like the property does not exist.

Ah no - the above is an abstraction to keep it simple. The issue is still exactly the same, though.

Ah explains. Sorry but I don't have any other suggestions.
